# How to share a post with image using addThis plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

How can i share a post in facebook with the image using addThis. I have written this code to share in facebook,twitter and mail.

Now i can able to post or share the content without having the image and am getting like this(Refer Image)[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o9pV.png).

Please help me to post with the image and caption.

I have added my code in fiddle or even you can see it in this https://jsfiddle.net/x34nnwcs/

```js
(function () {
    
    addthis.init();

    function navigatePage(e) {
        var pageId = $(this).attr("id"),
            $pageContent, sharingMarkup, content,
            config = $.extend(true, {}, window.addthis_config),
            share = $.extend(true, {}, window.addthis_share);

        if (pageId != "pageContent") {

            config["some_property"] = "some value";
            share.title = $(this).html();
            share.url = "http://" + pageId + ".not-a-tld";
      share.photo = "http://res-5.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/dpr_1.0,f_auto,w_365,h_133,c_fill,g_south,o_60/group.jpg";
            $pageContent = $("#pageContent");
            sharingMarkup = $("#sharing_markup").html();
            content = $(".pageC").html();
            console.log(content);
            $pageContent.html(content + sharingMarkup);            
            addthis.toolbox(".page_sharing_toolbox", config, share);            
            addthis.toolbox(".page_sharing_facebook", config, share);
                                 
        }
        $("#page1").click(navigatePage);
    }

    navigatePage.call(document.getElementById("pageContent"));

}());
```

```html
<div id="pageContent">    
    
        <button id="page1">Page 1</button>
         <div class='pageC'>
         
         
         <img src='http://res-5.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/dpr_1.0,f_auto,w_365,h_133,c_fill,g_south,o_60/group.jpg'/>
    <p>this is a simple paragraph that is meant to be nice and easy to type which is why there will be mommas no periods or any capital letters so i guess this means that it cannot really be considered a paragraph but just a series of run on sentences this should help you get faster at typing as im trying not to use too many difficult words in it although i think that i might start making it hard by including some more difficult letters I'm typing pretty quickly so forgive me for any mistakes i think that i will not just tell you a story about the time i went to the zoo and found a monkey and a fox playing together they were so cute and i think that they were not supposed to be in the same cage but they somehow were and i loved watching them horse</p>
    <p>   
    </div>    
</div>

<script id="sharing_markup" type="text/html">
    <div class="page_sharing_facebook addthis_toolbox facebook_like">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" title="Facebook Like"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="page_sharing_toolbox addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" style="width:290px;">
        <div class="share-icons" id="share-icons">
            <a class="addthis_button_email left" title="Email"></a>            
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook left" title="Facebook"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_twitter left last" title="Twitter"></a>            
            <a class="addthis_button_google left" title="Google"></a>            
        </div>  
    </div>
</script>
<script id="page1content" type="text/html">
   
</script>



<!-- the async parameter has been added, query parameter style, to the hash so that things won't render until you explicitly call addthis.init() -->
<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#async=1&pubid=atblog"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need only to add this meta tag to your `<Head>` on HTML code

```
<meta content="your image source" property="og:image">
```

Comment: Actually I tried meta tag also. But its not working. My Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x34nnwcs/3/ . If anything wrong let me know please.

Comment: your code is true try to clear your cached image on your browser,,, yes yes some times image not appear on AddThis popup but when you share post look at your facebook post you will see image